# Custom PHP MVC Framework: How to ensure locational compatibility with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am developing a PHP MVC framework based CMS system.

I have the following directory structure on my WAMP server:

```
c:/<webroot>/application/ (contains all Ms Vs and Cs)
c:/<webroot>/config/ (contains application.ini)
c:/<webroot>/public/ (contains /img, /js, & /css)
c:/<webroot>/index.php (entry point of MVC)
c:/<webroot>/.htaccess
```

.htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

There are no .htaccess files anywhere else in the system.

the .htaccess rules are intended to be implemented to rewrite the URL with Zend-framework style http://HTTP_HOST/controller/action/key/value/.../key/value/ style URLS

As far as I can tell, this is working pretty well when the MVC is sitting at the root of the web host.

As soon as I go one folder deep, however, everything falls apart:
Say for instance, I want a MVC website to be hosted from the root, and its MVC-based CMS hosted on level deep (/admin/). Having the .htaccess file above seems to bounce all requests to the CMS back to the root site... Do I need a different .htaccess rule for each folder? Is there a rule that can be written to ignore requests to the CMS by the root .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Comment: You have 2 options: 1) create another .htaccess with required rules in `/admin/` folder -- it will only work for URLs that start with `/admin/`; 2) place all rewrite rules into .htaccess in root folder, but rules for CMS (`/admin/`) place before MVC rules.

Comment: #1 - You should make this a full on ANSWER to this question, not a comment. #2 - Can you provide an example of the .htaccess file content for both folders? I tried this, I believe, but regardless of having both, the rewrite rules in the ROOT folder superceeded the ones in the subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess rules are enforced based on the directory hierarchy.  If no .htaccess rule is located within a sub-directory, then it will abide by the rules defined in the parent directory (or higher until an .htaccess file is found).  If an .htaccess file is located within a sub-directory, the rules enforced are a cumulation of rules already defined plus any superseding rules that are defined.

In your case, you could write rules within your root .htaccess to deal with an admin sub-directory.  However, it is probably easier and more clear to define a new .htaccess file within the admin sub-directory.

Comment: If I did the easier/more clear approach, what do I need to put in the .htaccess files in both folders so that the ones in the root do not "intercept" requests intended for the subfolder?